# Generating unipolar and bipolar voltages from AD5752

Tags: dac

The AD5752 consists of two DACs internally.

Can I use one DAC to generate unipolar voltage and another DAC for bipolar voltage simultaneously?

It is a dual channel DAC.

[Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5722_5732_5752.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage range applies to both channels.  If you supply it with +-10V, then both channels can output voltages in the range of +-10V.

There's nothing that says you **have** to put out negative voltages, though.

You can send values to one DAC that always generate positive voltages.  That's your "unipolar" output.

You can send values to one DAC that generate positive and negative voltages - that's your "bipolar" output.

Or, you can send "bipolar" signals to both DACs.

If you only need positive output, then you can supply it from a single supply, and not be able to generate negative voltages at all.

Comment: @ JRE  So can i generate both unipolar and bipolar voltages from each of the dac by suppllying bipolar supply voltage ?

Comment: Yes. If you need a bipolar output, you **must** use a bipolar supply.

Comment: can i generate both unipolar and bipolar volatage outputs simultaneously ?

Comment: Yes.  As I said in the answer, you have to use a bipolar supply because you need a biploar output but you don't have to send bipolar data to both channels.

Comment: @JREI am using AD5752 chip for new board design. I have provision for +12V supply for the DAC, but I am not sure about -12V supply for DAC. Should I go for some OP am based solution or any chips which convert +12V to -12V?

Comment: Opamps have to have a negative supply voltage if you expect a negative output.  You'll need to either supply your board with a negative voltage, or else use a small switching converter on the board to generate the negative voltage.  It is probably simpler to use a converter module (on or off board) than to design and build your own.

Comment: Ya got it. I am thinking of using LTM8027 for generating -12V  https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8027fd.pdf

Comment: Do you need 4A of current, and do you really want to deal with a ball grid array part?

Comment: The package is not a problem, and we are using the HEP-185-12A power supply to generate 12V from the AC supply.

Comment: I mean:  do you really expect to consume 4A from your -12V supply?  If not, then the LTM8027 is over kill.  As I understand it, you need a bit of current for your signal.  A DAC won't output any large current, nor consume much either.  A smaller (cheaper) -12V converter might be all you need.

Comment: As well, a smaller module might be cleaner.  With any switching power supply, you get noise and interference.  One built for lower current may be cleaner than one built for high current.

Comment: yeah you're right. Will consider the points you mentioned.Thank you for the inputs and suggestions